# How to avoid impredicative polymorphism and define lens of lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, impredicativetypes

I am trying to generate lens for data type with a lens field.

```
data St st l = St {
  _st_s :: String,
  _st_lens :: Lens' st l
}

st_lens :: forall st l. Lens' (St st l) (Lens' st l)
st_lens = lens _st_lens (\s a -> s { _st_lens = a })
```

GHC 8.10.7 gives me an error:

```
Illegal polymorphic type:
    forall (f1 :: * -> *). Functor f1 => (l -> f1 l) -> st -> f1 st
  GHC doesn't yet support impredicative polymorphism
• In the expansion of type synonym ‘Lens’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```hs
{-# Language ImpredicativeTypes #-}
{-# Language TypeApplications #-}
-- ..

st_lens :: forall st l. Lens' (St st l) (Lens' st l)
st_lens = lens @_ @(Lens' st l) _st_lens \s a -> s { _st_lens = a }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me in GHC 8.10, even when I also turn on `BlockArguments` and `ScopedTypeVariables`. The error is `Couldn't match expected type ‘(l -> f1 l) -> st -> f1 st’ with actual type ‘Lens' st l’`. It does work fine in 9.2, but then so does the asker's original code if you just enable `ImpredicativeTypes`, without needing any type applications.

Answer (score 3):

With GHC 9.2 or above, you can turn on `ImpredicativeTypes`, as demonstrated by [Iceland_jack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70130416/2751851). If you can't switch GHC versions right now, one pre-9.2 alternative is [storing your lens as an `ALens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#t:ALens), and then using either [`cloneLens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:cloneLens) or [the adapted combinators](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#g:10) to make use of it:

```
data St st l = St {
  _st_s :: String,
  _st_lens :: ALens' st l
}

st_lens :: forall st l. Lens' (St st l) (ALens' st l)
st_lens = lens _st_lens (\s a -> s { _st_lens = a })
```

```
ghci> ("foo", 15) ^# (St "bar" _1 ^. st_lens)
"foo"
ghci> ("foo", 15) ^. cloneLens (St "bar" _1 ^. st_lens)
"foo"
```